# Transpose in excel using VB

Tags: vb.net, excel

I am using VB to show large data in excel. They show up in A1:A3000. I am transposing A1:A6 to B1:G1 using this code:

```
sheet.Range("A1:A6").Copy()
sheet.Range("B1").PasteSpecial(Transpose:=True)
```

It's working but I'm facing trouble for repeating this process upto A3000. Basically I want to convert 1 column x3000 rows data into 6 columns x 500 rows data i.e the end result should have 500 rows and columns B:G

Comment: If your excel version or the workbook version is 2003 or earlier, a sheet may only have 255 columns.

Comment: And making 6 columns with 1 column is definitely NOT about transposing

Comment: Oh... it's a duplicated! That's why after I posted the answer I didn't see the answer. Because I was looking at the other post!

Answer (score 0):

Does this work for you?

```
Sub Test()
  Dim R1 As Long, R2 As Long, C2 As Long
  R2 = 1
  C2 = 2
  For R1 = 1 To ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
    Cells(R2, C2) = Cells(R1, 1)
    If C2 < 7 Then
      C2 = C2 + 1
    Else
      R2 = R2 + 1
      C2 = 2
    End If
  Next R1
End Sub
```

Comment: It gives an error "Member not found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80020003 (DISP_E_MEMBERNOTFOUND))" in the line `Cells(R2, C2) = Cells(R1, 1)`.

Comment: stenci's code works for me. If you are running this from VB.NET then it is probably a problem with the way you have translated it from VBA. In VB.NET you'll probably need to use `Cells(..).Value` explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

I'm just checking for an empty cell ("") to decide when to stop. Determining the number of rows at the outset would be more efficient (rather than checking for an empty cell each time) but with 3000 rows this is not a big deal:

```
Sub TransA()
    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Integer

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    j = 1
    For i = 1 To Rows.Count Step 6
        If Cells(i, "A") = "" Then
            Exit For
        Else
            Range(Cells(j, "B"), Cells(j, "G")).Formula = _
                Evaluate("=TRANSPOSE(A" & i & ":A" & i + 5 & ")")
            j = j + 1
        End If
    Next i
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

It could be modified to use Copy/PasteSpecial, but I like `Evaluate`.